# Instantiate generic field with <this.class>

Tags: java, java-8

I have following code

```
public class ComplicatedBuilder extends MyBuilder
{
  public final Parameter<ComplicatedBuilder, Long> par1 = new Parameter<>(this);
  public final Parameter<ComplicatedBuilder, Long> par2 = new Parameter<>(this);
  ...
}

public class Parameter<B extends MyBuilder, T>
{
  private T val;
  private B builder;
  public Parameter(B b)
  {
    builder = b;
  }

  public B setValue(T v)
  {
    val = v;
    return builder;
  }
  ...
}

//usage:
ComplicatedBuilder builder = new ComplicatedBuilder();
builder
  .par1.setValue(5)
  .par2.setValue(7);
```

How could I declare parameters with something like `public final Parameter<this.class, Long> par1 ...`? I want to do it in manner that allows to copy-paste parameters list to another builder without a lot of changes.

Comment: Can you give an example? I would say you need to use more generics. Most builders are generated code from a data model if they start to get complicated or difficult to maintain.

Comment: You can’t. And optimizing code for easy copy&paste is not a useful goal. At some point, you will have all the copies your need, so the advantage is gone and only the legacy remains. Note that most IDEs adapt all references when copying a class, i.e. when you copy `ComplicatedBuilder`, the internal `Parameter`’s type parameters are adapted as well. Besides that, you can use features like “Local Rename” (Eclipse) to redirect all references within a single class to another class. But if this is a recurring problem,i.e. if all these builders have common parameters, you should rethink your design…

Comment: I know that copy&paste is not a very good technique, but now I am looking for something before we can introduce code generation that will generate java builders from DSL.
In case of few builders with 5 common parameters and 2 specific I could try to extract commons to base class, but it will introduce some restrictions on order of setting parameters, i.e. I will need to set parameters of the base class after all parameters from sub-classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you mean this?

```
abstract class AbstractComplicatedBuilder<B extends AbstractComplicatedBuilder<B>> 
                         extends MyBuilder {
    public final Parameter<B, Long> par1 = new Parameter<>(self());
    public final Parameter<B, Long> par2 = new Parameter<>(self());

    abstract B self();
}

class ComplicatedBuilder extends AbstractComplicatedBuilder<ComplicatedBuilder>{
    ComplicatedBuilder self(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

you can defer which actual `AbstractComplicatedBuilder` to build using generic argument `B extends AbstractComplicatedBuilder<B>` .

Comment: It costs one additional class, but solves the problem. But may be I give up supporting of the current design to eliminate the problem itself.

Comment: @DmitryBulashevich yes, it solved by introduce an abstract class, but you can redesign your classes using this clue that Holger has been said.

Comment: @DmitryBulashevich there is a good example of builder pattern from [spring-security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/SecurityConfigurer.html).

Comment: @DmitryBulashevich I having extracted build patterns of spring-security on [gitbub](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/master/src/test/java/test/java/patterns/BuilderPatternTest.java#L20-L45), and each of build pattern is a little complex in turn.